# I don't understand the new jQuery.sub() function

Tags: jquery

Can someone explain me the new sub function of jQuery http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.sub/

Please give your own example that's easy to follow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Side-by-side jQueries

It creates a side-by-side jQuery object with different capabilities.
You could provide some plugins in one and others in the other jQuery instance created by `jQuery.sub()`.

### Real-world example

One usage example I can think of is having two public plugins with the same name but different functionality/working so you could load the first in one jQuery and the second in the other jQuery. This way you'd be able to use both even though they share the same name.

But otherwise I think function's quite nicely explained on jQuery documentation anyway. I don't think it needs any additional explanation. It only lacks some credible example that shows a very useful usage scenario.

### Actual example

jQuery plugins these days will have to be changed to support this functionality, because they usually do this:

```
(functio($){
    // plugin code
})(jQuery);
```

As you can see this function closure parameter is hardcoded to jQuery. To include a particular plugin in its own jQuery realm (that you as a developer define), this code should be changed to:

```
var $$ = jQuery.sub();
(functio($){
    // plugin code
})($$);
```

But this would mean that developers would always have to change plugin code which is not really helpful. I suppose jQuery will have to come up with some sort of plugin manager so loading plugins would only load them inside this manager and you'd have to include them in jQuery object by using this manager and providing jQuery realm.

I don't see any other possibility of making plugins generic so they can be used in any jQuery instance without changing plugin code.

Example presented in original documentation is some sort of a *let them see how it can be done* but I don't think that's a very good example bacuse it just puts all `sub()` plugins under a common original jQuery plugin (in that example it's `myplugin()`).

Comment: e.g. we have a page that uses the old [bassistance.de autocomplete plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) that we need to load into a div in a page that has all of jQuery UI loaded, including its autocomplete control. Both define `$.autocomplete`. We could potentially use a jQuery.sub to allow the loaded div to load the bassistance autocomplete and use it as before without interfering with the rest of the page that uses the jQuery UI autocomplete. (Although in practice I think we're just going to rename one of the functions.)

Comment: @Rup: Exactly what I talked about. Thanks for plugins example that clash in name.

Comment: @robert: Ok i think I understand but not completly. Can you show some basic code?

Comment: @learningdb: I've edited my answer to point out the obvious problem with existing plugins and `sub()` functionality.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does creating these new instances of jQuery have an adverse affect of memory usage, or is there javascript trickery going on that doesn't really duplicate the whole jQuery object?

Comment: @xzyfer: **Very good question**. To answer it would mean to actually check `sub()` code which I didn't do so I hope someone else could answer this particular question. But based on the fact that **any** functionality could be modified I think everything is duplicated. There's no functionality in jQuery that would have an intermediate functionality to detect when something gets changed which would intercept such a change and only do duplication of that partocular part at that very point. Based on this thinking I guess jQuery is duplicated. Completely. But as said. I haven't checked.

Comment: I'll have to check into it. My concern being if each new plugin creates a new instance of the jQuery object that's a lot of potentially wasted memory. And considering the amount of pages/developers I've come across happy to just throw another plugin in, it could be chaos.

Comment: @xzyfer: I don't think it actually meant for each plugin to define itself in a separate jQuery instance. That should be on you. The developer. As much as I understand this. Following the example on documentation would still make it possible for various plugins to clash in names.

Comment: Ok, my understand was that each current practice of encapsulating your plugin with a jQuery instance (functio($){ // plugin code })(jQuery), which as far as I know is considered good practice, was to be replaced by instead encapsulating it within a new instance of jQuery. So assuming each plugin developer was doing so, more plugins == more jQuery objects, unless you take it about yourself to modify your 3rd party plugins load some/all into a single new jQuery instance ala HTML5Boilerplate. I think this will take some investigation.

Comment: Defining the plugin on a sub means it won't work on the original object, only that sub. Why would I want a new sub for each plugin?

And what is the whole purpose of cloning jQuery for making functions - can't I just make my own function and be done with?

Answer (score 0):

That's if you want to make a variation of jQuery - for example, if you want to override some of the jQuery methods, but still retain the originals if you want to use them later.

Comment: i know about the link..i have posted it in my original ques

Comment: Alright, I removed it - but the examples it gives there are very basic stuff. Not sure how it can be demonstrated with more basic examples. I believe that Robert has also explained it quite well.